# How to organize TypeScript interfaces

Tags: typescript

I would like to know what the recommended way is to organize interface definitions in typescript. In my project I have many different classes. Each class can have a configuration interface. Currently I have gathered all of these interface definitions into one file `Interfaces.ts` and reference the file from various locations.

Is there a better way?

Example: https://github.com/blendsdk/blendjs/blob/devel/blend/src/common/Interfaces.ts

Comment: Until something like StyleCop exists for TypeScript, the argument for "personal preference" will probably apply (as long as your code compiles). My personal preference is to split everything down into it's own file i.e. interface IValidatable would live in IValidatable.ts - Yes, you end up with a whole lot of files essentially, but it should help with maintainability over time.

Answer (score 150):

## Global

The TypeScript team uses a file called `types.ts` : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/types.ts

I do the same in my project e.g. https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/master/src/common/types.ts

## Alternative

Its okay for *high* reuse portions to belong in `types`, however don't pollute it with specific types. Specific types can be (should be) closer to their reference e.g. react style props belong next to (in the same file as) the react component.

[React Component Prop Type](https://github.com/basarat/gls/blob/63fd7fc3d06aa7301245290b6db42a7766649f81/src/components/vertical.tsx#L25-L30) / [React Component](https://github.com/basarat/gls/blob/63fd7fc3d06aa7301245290b6db42a7766649f81/src/components/vertical.tsx#L35-L59)

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful! I wonder, do you put the type definitions from `types.ts` into the global namespace or do you reference `types.ts` from every file that uses its types?

Comment: @basarat any update to Rotareti's question? I am curious to know that as well.

Comment: Hey @basarat, can you please answer?

Comment: `do you reference types.ts from every file that uses its types` Always prefer reference. Globals never scale 

Comment: is this really a better way to organize types? a 6000+ line file with all types it does not look very maintainable, perhaps it would be better to split it up per component.

Comment: @Chris agreed. High reuse base is a subset of the full number of types for most projects. So added an example 

Comment: With all due respect @basarat, I strongly disagree with organizing types this way. Sure, we all are capable of CTRL+F, but why not organize these more granularly? Just use a types file for each feature or section of the project. Whenever I see a file with 700+ lines of code I feel bad for the poor developer who will have to go through all of it.

Comment: So is using `index.d.ts` not recommended any more ?

Comment: Also is it recommended to add this folder to `typeRoots` in the `tsconfig` file ?

Answer (score 33):

I like to structure my apps like this:

```
|-- app
    |-- components
    |-- directives
    |-- services
    |-- interfaces
        |-- <feature/component name>
            |-- <interface name>.interface.ts
```

Comment: This approach can be really difficult to scale. A better options could be use [colocation aproach](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/colocation). To help enable a more maintainable codebase, we should co-locate our types/interfaces files with the file or group of files that implement them.

Comment: I have to agree with @CristianFlórez here. I'm seeing several boilerplate Node.js + TypeScript project layouts that feature an "interfaces" directory at the top-level. This seems awkward. What's the purpose of this separation? I think if you define a service (e.g. 'notifier.ts') why wouldn't you either define the interfaces within that file or define them alongside it (e.g. 'notifier.interfaces.ts')? And while you're at it, add the test definitions (e.g. 'notifier.tests.ts')?

Answer (score 27):

My projects are constructed like this

```sh
src/
└── ts
    ├── enums
    │   ├── app_enums.ts
    │   └── db_enums.ts
    ├── interfaces
    │   ├── app_interfaces.ts
    │   ├── db_interfaces.ts
    │   └── global_interfaces.ts
    └── types
        └── app_types.ts
```

Comment: What's the difference between the `interfaces` and `types` folder?

Comment: @lion_bash Directories names express their purpose well. `interfaces` directory includes all interfaces and types directory includes all type aliases you use in your project.You can merge these directories if you wish but I found splitting types semantically and structurally is really helpful when managing large code bases. Try to figure out what works best for you. There is no golden rule when it comes to project directory structure

Comment: I think I would use this approach in a slightly different way. I would create a global `/ts` folder for types/interfaces that are used by many sections of the project, and in order to take advantage of the colocation approach. I would also create local `/ts`for each section of the project (e.g. a folder that contains related react components.) Are there any obvious drawbacks to this approach that I am not aware of?

Comment: @H.B. Sounds like a plan.