# Passing an Array of Objects to an Imported Function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've got a function module in `list-full-names.ts`:

```
export default function listFullNames(namesList) {
    let fullNames: string[] = namesList.map(item => {
        return `${item.first} ${item.last}`;
    });
    
    return fullNames;
}
```

And a file that imports the function and passes it an array of objects:

```
import listFullNames from './list-full-names';

interface NameProps {
    first: string;
    last: string;
}

const names: NameProps[] = [
    {first: 'John', last: 'Smith'},
    {first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe'},
    {first: 'David', last: 'Bowie'}
];

let fullNames = listFullNames(names);
```

Typescript throws errors on `list-full-names.ts` because it doesn't know what type `namesList` is. I know I could put the `NameProps` interface in a separate file and import it to `list-full-names.ts` but it feels weird to separate the type definition from the data it's describing. I also don't like that I have to import the interface in every file that accepts the `names` array as a possible property.

Is there a best practices for this kind of thing? What's the recommended way to handle this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-m7x9sv?file=/index.ts) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a *one-size fits all* approach, everyone has their option and some approaches may not apply to all projects. So it depends...

Here's my take...

Firstly, if you have a type that you really don't plan on passing around everywhere, say an exported function with a string union argument type.

```
type MyType = 'good' | 'bad';
export function isGoodType(type: MyType) {
  return type === 'good';
}
```

In this case, defining `MyType` in this is the best option as there is really no need to export it.

The second case is more like your example, where you have a type that you want to pass around to other files. Where you put the type here is really up to you but ideally you keep dependent types together. For example...

```
export interface NameProps {
  first: string;
  last: string;
}
export interface Response {
  data: NameProps[]
}
```

In your case this would mean you need to import the `NameProps` type into the `list-full-names.ts` file. You could even use a [type import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#importing-types) to specify the type without accidentally creating a circular dependency.

```
// list-full-names.ts
import type { NameProps } from './names';

export default function listFullNames(namesList: NameProps[]) {
  let fullNames: string[] = namesList.map((item) => {
    return `${item.first} ${item.last}`;
  });

  return fullNames;
}
```

> See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mclaren-5jyr8p?file=/option-1/list-full-names.ts) example

But when I have a lot of types that I want to define that may or may not depend on each other, I typically create a `types.ts` file adjacent to where it's used and simply import it wherever I need it. This `types.ts` file kinda acts like an `index.ts` for types. You could also adopt a file naming pattern like `names.types.ts`. See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mclaren-5jyr8p?file=/option-2/list-full-names.ts) example.

Here's some other ideas:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/hknqf4/where_to_put_my_typesinterfaces/
- [How to organize TypeScript interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633033/how-to-organize-typescript-interfaces)

Comment: Thank you for this super thorough answer! I'll play around with it and see which approach feels best.